# Mismatch between query forward and return values

Tags: next.js

my request url '/api/...&propertyId=**gm%5Ck**'

but req.query return {propertyId: **gm\k**} in next.js api routes

Why does this happen? I don't understand at all...

Answer (score 1):

That's because Next is decoding uri's under the hood. `%5C` is URL escape code for backslash character: `\`:

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent("\\")) // '%5C'

console.log(decodeURIComponent("%5C")) // '\\'
```

So if you need to preserve the URL form of the string, try to run `encodeURIComponent(propertyId)`.

NOTE: Why the *two* backslashes? Because backslash is a special escape character, thus it needs to be escaped itself.

Answer (score 0):

it called URL encoded character, you can reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP, section: ASCII Encoding Reference